# Androistudio grey package can't add to repository

Tags: java, android, git, android-studio

There is a grey package in my project which git can't see the changes of :

[image]

Any idea on how to correct that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you maybe ignore that package by accident ? 
Try to look for a .gitignore file in your project root folder and take a look at its content.

Comment: Haha, i guess i was right. Please set the answer as accepted :D

Comment: Yes that's it, though I don't know when it happened :)

Comment: Sometimes stuff like this happens when you click around. Maybe you did right click on that package chose git in the context menu and pressed ignore instead of add.

Comment: I'm doing some heavy refactoring so that's not impossible (there is a 10min delay before accepting an answer, you were too fast)

Comment: Ok anyhow, it happend at some point :D. Ah okay, it would be nice if you could remember, trying to earn some reputation today ;).

Comment: Don't worry about that ;)